# In Line Runner, what does "Restoring transactions" mean?

Tags: applications

I was wondering, when I open the Line Runner app, I get this message saying 'restoring transactions'. What is that? This also occasionally happens when pressing the play button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that the app is checking the Play Store to see if you have made any in-app purchases that have not yet been activated on that device. It is normal behaviour, you don't need to worry about it.